# How to get a graphic with ggparliament that shows the desired colors for each political party?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph with the results of the last elections in Spain. I have a dataframe with a variable character in which I store the name of the party and another with the seats obtained.
Then I add a third variable with the desired color codes for each match and proceed to use ggparliament as indicated in the help. The problem is that I got the graphic but only one color is shown for all the seats.

This is the dataframe with which I start:

```
party            seats 

PSOE              123
PP                66
Ciudadanos        57
Podemos           42
Vox               24
ERC               15
JxCAT             7
PNV               6
Bildu             4
CCa-PNC           2
NA+               2
COMPROMIS         1
PRC               1
```

And it is the list with the colors that I want (In order according to the result of the political party)

```
colors <- c("FF0000", "0000FF", "EB6109", "672F6C", "00FF00", "FFB232",
             "CE3751", "bfae4a", "b5cf18","bfae4a","d20e07","ffb232","ffcd20")
```

And here is the code:

```
df<-data.frame(df,colors)
```

```
spain_semicircle <- parliament_data(election_data = df,
                                       type = "semicircle",
                                       parl_rows = 10,
                                       party_seats = df$seats
                                     )
```

```
spain <- ggplot(spain_semicircle, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = party)) +
  geom_parliament_seats() + 
  theme_ggparliament() +
  labs(colour = NULL, 
       title = "Congreso de los Diputados") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = spain_semicircle$colors, 
                      limits = spain_semicircle$party)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is with your `scale_colour_manual()`. Running the code without it produces the plot. Wonder why...

Comment: Yes, but if I remove that part the graphic is created with the colors of the rainbow (I guess those in the current palette), I need it to use the list of colors I entered. How could I do it? What do I have wrong in the code if I want to use those colors that I have indicated?

Comment: I changed scale_colour_manual manually and now it works: `scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "cornflowerblue", "orange", "purple", "green2", "gold",
                                 "darksalmon", "darkgreen", "greenyellow","yellow","snow2","orange","steelblue"), 
                      limits = c("PSOE ","PP ","Cs ","Podemos ","VOX ","ERC-SOBIRANISTES ","JxCAT-JUNTS ","EAJ-PNV ","EH Bildu ","CCa-PNC ","NA+ ","COMPROMÍS 2019 ","PRC ") `

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the hex colors that you supplied are invalid. With the manual colors that you supplied in the comments, you can use the following solution:

Use the vector `colors` without adding it to your `df` data frame.

```
library(ggparliament)
df <- read.table(text = "party            seats 
                         PSOE              123
                         PP                66
                         Ciudadanos        57
                         Podemos           42
                         Vox               24
                         ERC               15
                         JxCAT             7
                         PNV               6
                         Bildu             4
                         CCa-PNC           2
                         NA+               2
                         COMPROMIS         1
                         PRC               1", header = T)
```

Edited valid color names supplied in the comments:

```
colors <- c("red", "cornflowerblue", "orange", "purple", "green2", "gold", "darksalmon", 
            "darkgreen", "greenyellow","yellow","snow2","orange","steelblue")
```

Instead of appending colors to `df` we'll directly go apply the `parliament_data` function.

```
spain_semicircle <- parliament_data(election_data = df,
                                    type = "semicircle",
                                    parl_rows = 10,
                                    party_seats = df$seats)


ggplot(spain_semicircle, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = party)) +
  geom_parliament_seats() + 
  theme_ggparliament() +
  labs(colour = "", 
       title = "Congreso de los Diputados") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colors)   # set the values argument to our vector colors
```

[image]

Comment: We also need to add the line `limits = df$party` to `scale_colour_manual` so that the colors paint exactly the match we want.(For example, PSOE is the red party in Spain) Anyway, thanks for the response, before you gave me the clue I needed to get it and now I have incorporated colors into the function making the code cleaner, if you edit the answer and add that line, I'll mark it as correct (maybe someone comes here wanting to order the colors and that helps). Thank you, OTStats!

Comment: Ahhh, very true. I'll revise!